# which is a better method to use for signing messages between two parties in web3?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethereumjs, state-channels

I have been searching for a while for the most secure and supported way for off-chain channel messaging.....so i was using `web3.eth.sign(address, keccak256(msg))` for singing messages ....but then used to get a BIG FAT notification in MetaMask when signing that "this is unSafe"....so i started using:

```js
web3.currentProvider.sendAsync(
      {
        method: "eth_signTypedData",
        params: [msgParams, web3.eth.defaultAccount],
        from: web3.eth.defaultAccount
      }, [, call])
```

as mentioned in this [article](https://medium.com/metamask/scaling-web3-with-signtypeddata-91d6efc8b290) by Official MetaMask that its more safe and make more sense that the user SHOULD know what they are signing.... but then i get this BIG FAT warning in the console that says:

> MetaMask: This experimental version of eth_signTypedData will be
>   deprecated in the next release in favor of the standard as defined in
>   EIP-712. See https://git.io/fNzPl for more information on the new
>   standard.

when followed the link didn't get a clear answer....so anyone here could help with which way to with ???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which version of web3 do you use?

Comment: version 1.0.0-beta.55